# Canonical question for Cartesian product

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, canonical

I just came across several recent questions asking variations of "how to find all possible combinations of multiple lists", and I regularly see similar questions. The reason that people post new questions instead of finding older Q&A's seems to be that most people don't know the term "Cartesian Product", and use a variety of ways to describe the problem.
Is there a canonical question that these questions should be marked as a duplicate of?

And, more generally, is there a mechanism for users to find canonical questions about subjects for which they don't know the correct terminology?

Comment: As far as I know, the only mechanism we've got is manual keyword population in canonical questions (or dupes) of all the known ways to describe a particular term.